# Rails - how to make your app work with multiple sub-domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a RoR app.  I would like to allow multiple clients of mine use it as a cloud based application.  I don't want to have to duplicate the code for each customer.

I assume this means using a subdomain for each of my customers, and have a table for Customers.  The Customers table would have a field for the domain.

In other words -- I want each customer to only see their records.

My questions are:

- Has someone documented how to do this in Rails?  Where is it?
- Would every table have to have a customer_id in it?  Or if you have a Project table with the Customer_id, and then have tasks for the Project, you wouldn't need the customer_id in the Task record - right?
- Would you have to start each view with Customer.  ??

Any thoughts would help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a railscast about handling subdomains in Rails 3 here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Regarding point 2, you'd just need the `customer_id` on `Project`, you wouldn't need it on `Task` as well.

I'm not sure what you mean about starting each view with Customer., but I'm guessing not. Maybe going through the railscast will answer your question here.

Comment: Railscasts is a great resource!  It really got me started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to think about authorisation, ie does the current user have the permission to view/update these records?  I personally recommend the cancan gem for this purpose https://github.com/ryanb/cancan, you define a single model/abilities.rb file in your app that contains all the permissions for your user.  I've found it works really well.

Comment: No problem. Could you give me a mark for my effort? ..I need all the points I can get ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Has someone documented how to do this in Rails? Where is it?

The whole thing? Not that I am aware of.

For the subdomain? Yes, and it is called *catch-all A record*, *catch-all subdomain*, ... etc.
Simply, add a wildcard (*) `A record` to the domain and then use `request.subdomain` in RoR to extract the subdomain requested.

@cheeseweasal answered the rest.